# The opposite of "an action in vain"

Tags: phrase-requests

I wonder what is the opposite of "an action in vain"? I thought of "a useful action", but I would prefer a phrase like "an action in ABC". Is there one like that?

Comment: Almost certainly, there is no such phrase.

Could you re-phrase your Question to include the possibility of something like *a successful action*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "action in vain" isn't always simply useless;  in fact, the phrase is most often used to describe an effort to accomplish something quite important, that may require a great deal of effort or skill, but which proves to be beyond the capability of the actor.  You often hear this phrase to describe an heroic but untimately unsuccessful rescue, or, in war, a strategy that fails.

Because this is a fixed expression, there is likely no well-recognized similar phrase for an action which succeeds.   That sort of action would be more likely described as, "a brilliant action that carried the day", or "his actions were (heroic, timely, effacacious, effective, rewarded with success, etc.)